# Check, if database is currently used, before removing it

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup, pascalscript

My application creates and uses database to store all the data. It is implied, that this database can be also used by another users in shared network.
For now, i'm working on uninstallation of application, and removing database will be part of full uninstallation process. I'm removing it with next statement

```
Query := '"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = ''DentalDesktop'') BEGIN ALTER DATABASE DentalDesktop SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE DentalDesktop; END"';
Params := '-U ' + sUserName + ' -P ' + sPassword + ' -S ' + server + ' -Q ' + Query;
ShellExec('', 'sqlcmd', Params, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

where `sUserName`, `sPassword`, `server` are server parameters.
But if database is used while uninstalling, there might be numerous problems. So, is there way to check, if database is currently used, inside Inno Setup installer?

Comment: Do you read this topic
 http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/how-can-i-tell-if-a-sql-server-database-is-still-being-used

Comment: My "take it offline" based answer is still waiting in "your answer" box..

Comment: @David, npt really. Question in your link looks more like "what to do, if you need to shut down your database, while someone might use it". I'd prefer to do nothing, if database is currently used.

Comment: you might use dynamic view sys.dm_exec_sessions, also create logic depends on either particular users, computers or status that you don't want to kick off

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, thx, it is probably most close to what i'm looking for. I think, i can use ADOConnection and ADORecordset to get results. All what's left is to figure out, what properties of set i need.